# Does tensorflow py_func support multiple augments?

Tags: tensorflow

Just as title. If it does, please give me an example how to pass multiple augments to py_func's first augment function. Thank you

Comment: What is an augment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, you just pass in a `list` of tensors that is then mapped to the argumets in your function. Similarly, you need to pass a list of output types for each output in the `return` statement:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def my_python_function(arg1, arg2):
  return arg1, arg2, arg1+arg2

input_tensor_1 = tf.constant([0,1,2,3,4,5])
input_tensor_2 = tf.constant([2,2,2,2,2,2])

res = tf.py_func(my_python_function, [input_tensor_1, input_tensor_2], [tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(res))
```

Running the previous sample you get:

```py
Out[17]: 
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]),
 array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it worked out!